# Assembler illegal memory reference

Tags: ассемблер, memory

```
cmp byte ptr [si], '-'
```

Ассемблер выдает ошибку illegal memory reference. В чем здесь ошибка?

Та же ошибка в строчке

```
mov word ptr [i1], bx
```

i1 - двойное слово

Компилятор TASM 16-bit режим IDEAL

Comment: SI на BX менять пробовали?

Comment: Попробовал, ошибка осталась.

Comment: Прошу прощения, после изменения на mov bl, [si] и cmp bl, '-' все заработало.

Comment: Какой именно ассемблер?

Comment: Компилятором fasm `cmp byte [si], '-'` успешно компилируется. У компилятора nasm синтаксис аналогичный, тоже должно компилироваться просто с byte. Через tasm/masm16 должно компилироваться с byte ptr.

Comment: @АртёмПопов, ваше дополнение к вопросу лучше оформить в виде ответа.

Answer (score 4):

Когда задаете вопрос по ассемблеру, нужно указывать архитектуру, "битность" и какой компилятор используется.

> Прошу прощения, после изменения на `mov bl, [si]` и `cmp bl, '-'` все заработало.

Это не решение проблемы, а "костыль".

По факту, вариант инструкции `cmp byte ptr [si], '-'` успешно компилируется компиляторами ml (masm32) и tasm, а вариант `cmp byte [si], '-'` успешно компилируется ассемблерами fasm и nasm.

## fasm:

```
; Компиляция: fasm <имя файла>
use16
cmp byte [si], '-'
```

На выходе получается файл с расширением bin и следующим содержимым:

```
80 3C 2D
```

Результат дизассемблирования в 16-битном режиме:

[image: disasm]

## nasm:

```
; Компиляция: nasm -f bin <имя_исходного_файла>.asm -o <имя_выходного_файла>.bin
section .text
cmp byte [si], '-'
```

После компиляции получается файл с расширением bin (как мы и указали при компиляции), и с тем же содержимым.

## masm

```
; Компиляция:
; ml /c <имя_входного_файла>.asm 
; link16 /t <имя_входного_файла>.obj,<имя_выходного_файла>.bin,nul,nul,nul

code segment
start:
    cmp byte ptr [si], '-'
code ends
end start
```

Компиляция проходит успешно, результат совпадает.

## tasm

Содержимое исходного файла то же что и в разделе masm. Компиляция:

```
tasm <имя_входного_файла>.asm
link16 /t <имя_входного_файла>.obj,<имя_выходного_файла>.bin,nul,nul,nul
```

tasm запускался под dosbox. Использовал линкер из пакета masm32, т.к. лень было разбираться еще и с ключами линкера от Borland.

Содержимое всех результирующих файлов совпадает:
[image: Результат поиска дубликатов]

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался с проблемой. Сработал вариант cmp [BYTE si], '-'. Наверное дело было в старом ассемблере TASM 3.0. Всем спасибо за ответы.